# How to initialize a RavenFS FileStore programatically when embedded with MVC

Tags: ravendb, asp.net-mvc-5.2, ravenfs

I can connect to a `FileStore` via a `RavenDBServer` instance in my MVC application provided the FS is initialized, so (for example), I create a `RavenDBServer` with the `DataDirectory` set:

**To be clear:** this is running as an *embedded* instance.

```
var config = new RavenConfiguration
{
    DataDirectory = "~\\App_Data\\Database",
    DatabaseName = "test"
};

var server = new RavenDbServer(config);
server.UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true;
```

Then go to the Raven UI, add a FS called `test-fs`, add the following to the initialization code:

```
server.FilesStore.DefaultFileSystem = "test-fs";
server.FilesStore.Initialize();
```

Then when I call:

```
server.FileStore.OpenAsyncSession("test-fs");
```

we're all good.

Ideally, I don't want to have to go about doing that as it's cumbersome, and involves changing code. SO. I put this in:

```
server.FilesStore.AsyncFilesCommands.Admin.CreateOrUpdateFileSystemAsync(new FileSystemDocument(), "test-fs");
```

but this never creates the `FileSystems` folder in the `App_Data` folder, and any attempt to `OpenAsyncSession` always results in an error stating that the `test-fs` could not be opened.

How can I create the FS on initialisation? I'm doing this within an MVC (5.2) application.

Answer (score 2):

See this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/Egok-GIVeAU) on the RavenDB Mailing List.

You could do it like this:

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {
    RunInMemory = true,
    EnlistInDistributedTransactions = false
};
store.Initialize();
RavenServer = store;

var createFs = Task.Run(async () => {
    await store.FilesStore.AsyncFilesCommands.Admin.CreateOrUpdateFileSystemAsync(
    new FileSystemDocument {
        Settings = {
            { "Raven/FileSystem/DataDir", "~/App_Data/FileSystem/default" }
        }
    },
    "default"
    ).ConfigureAwait(false);
});
createFs.Wait();
```

The next version should support in-memory file stores.

Comment: Hi Dusky, I'll give this a go in a short while - may I ask why the comments about in memory? I'm not attempting to run RavenFS InMemory, just as embedded.

Comment: Just in case. Some use an embedded in-memory instance for unit tests. Others may find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use static FileStoreHolder to provide FilesStore. As is recomended for DocumentStore.

```
 internal class FilesStoreHolder
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IFilesStore> Store = new Lazy<IFilesStore>(CreateStore);
    public static IFilesStore FilesStore
    {
        get { return Store.Value; }
    }

    private static IFilesStore CreateStore()
    {
        var store = new FilesStore
        {
          ConnectionStringName = "ConnStr",
          DefaultFileSystem = "MyFS"
        }.Initialize();

        return store;
    }
}
```

then when I need FS session I get it this way:

```
 using (var fsSession = FilesStoreHolder.FilesStore.OpenAsyncSession())
        {
            return await fsSession.DownloadAsync(Folder + name);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! You are using a `new FileStore()` instance, which is fine if you're running as a server and I should make it clearer that the question - but I am attempting to do this in an *embedded* mode.